# Проблема с доступом на шару по сетке.

Tags: active-directory, доступ

Доброго всем
Есть группа в AD (Activ Directoty)  например "отдел" - (AD под Win2003 sp2 Stand. Edition).
В ней пользователи "Иванов", "Петров", "Сидоров".
Почему при разрешении доступа к сетевому ресурсу, я даю группе "отдел" полный доступ на ресурс. Но пользователи по отдельности всё равно доступа к ресурсу не имеют.
Отчего может такое происходить?

Comment: Читать больно. >Проблема с доступом на шуру по сетке.>фул доступпочему все перемешивают слова русского и английского языка? Уж пишите либо по-русски либо по английски.

Comment: Извиняюсь, на ОСях аглицких видать перетрудился я :)

Comment: to: ZerglynДавал в безопасности.Сейчас попробую в разрешениях.

Comment: ОК! Все нормально теперь. Забыл админку совсем :(Zerglyn - Сэнькс, за подсказку!

Comment: @I_CaR, сли Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1](взято из ответа @shaman888)  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/lPQEm.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А где

> даю группе "отдел" фул доступ наресурс?

- в разрешениях на доступа к папке по сети
- или в настройка безопасности папки?